# Using Lax-Milgram for linear first order ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let us consider the following problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x'+x &=1\\
x(0) & = 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\qquad \text{over}\quad [\,0\,;\,1\,]\;.
$$
The unique solution is $x(t) = 1-e^{-t}$.

I would like to use the Lax-Milgram theory on this problem just for fun but I do not know which functional space to use nor which inner product. So I considered the space $C_0^1 = \{x\in C^1\mid x(0) = 0\}$ and then after multiplying by a function $v\in C_0^1$ and integrating I obtained
$$
\int_0^1x(t)(v(t)-v'(t)) dt + x(1)v(1) = \int_0^1v(t) dt 
$$
I am stuck here. Thank you for your help.